Why does this XAML and Class cause an netbroadcasteventwindow.4.0.0.0.13965fa.0: unknown hard error
When the compiler tries to compile this class in my project it shows an "Unknown Hard Error". When I remove this class everything is fine. Anyone know the reason why?
Code:
 public partial class CustomTooltip : IChartTooltip
 {
     private TooltipData _data;

     public CustomTooltip()
     {
         InitializeComponent();

         //LiveCharts will inject the tooltip data in the Data property
         //your job is only to display this data as required

         DataContext = this;
     }

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     public TooltipData Data
     {
         get { return _data; }
         set
         {
             _data = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("Data");

         }
     }

     public TooltipSelectionMode? SelectionMode { get; set; }

     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
     {
         if (PropertyChanged != null)
             PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
 }

<UserControl x:Class="UnkownErrorProject.CustomTooltip"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UnkownErrorProject"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" 
            d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:CustomTooltip}"
             Background="White" Padding="2 2" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Points}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpf:DataPointViewModel}">
                <Grid Margin="5">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <!-- Date -->
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <!-- Series Name, Rectangle, and Stock Level -->
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <!-- Rectangle and Series Name -->
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <!-- Stock Level -->
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- Top Row: Date -->
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                           Text="{Binding ChartPoint.Instance.Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd-MMM}}" 
                           Margin="0 5 0 10" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"/>

                    <!-- Second Row: Rectangle, Series Name, and Stock Level -->
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <!-- Rectangle -->
                        <Rectangle  Fill="{Binding Series.Stroke}" 
                               Height="15" Width="15" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                        <!-- Series Name -->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChartPoint.Instance.SeriesName}" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="DimGray"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <!-- Stock Level -->
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="{Binding ChartPoint.Instance.StockLevel, StringFormat={}{0:N2} m²}" 
                           Margin="5 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="DimGray"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>

I've looked up problems online and some point to a binding problem. Thing is all the code works correctly even with the error
Any help would be appreciated!
Using VS 2022 & .Net 4.8.1
